# Hive Current date function

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, beeline

I want to get the current date in beeline.

I tried to use this:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
```

it outputs this:

```
16-03-21
```

What I was looking to get it:

```
2016-03-21 09:34
```

How do I do it? I see the beeline documentation here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

But it didnt work for me.

Comment: It works on my end.  Select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) resulted in '2016-03-21 18:16:20'

Comment: but i need to convert this string to a date type to be inserted into an oracle date column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())) from my table ...
```

Results in '2016-03-21'

Answer (score 2):

you can get it by passing expected format as a parameter of from_unixtime function.

Example :

select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM');

Result:

2016-03-21 16:03

Answer (score 0):

there are many functions you can use in hive : taken from http://atiblog.com/date-function-hive/

1)from_unixtime:

This function converts the number of seconds from unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) to a STRING that represents the TIMESTAMP of that moment in the current system time zone in the format of “1970-01-01 00:00:00”. The following example returns the current date including the time.

`hive> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP());`
OK
2015–05–18 05:43:37
Time taken: 0.153 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

2)from_utc_timestamp:-
This function assumes that the string in the first expression is UTC and then, converts that string to the time zone of the second expression. This function and the to_utc_timestamp function do timezone conversions. In the following example, t1 is a string.
`hive> SELECT  from_utc_timestamp(‘1970-01-01 07:00:00’, ‘JST’);`
OK
1970–01–01 16:00:00
Time taken: 0.148 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

3)to_utc_timestamp:
This function assumes that the string in the first expression is in the timezone that is specified in the second expression, and then converts the value to UTC format. This function and the from_utc_timestamp function do timezone conversions.
`hive> SELECT to_utc_timestamp (‘1970-01-01 00:00:00’,‘America/Denver’);`
OK
1970–01–01 07:00:00
Time taken: 0.153 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

4)unix_timestamp :
This function converts the date to the specified date format and returns the number of seconds between the specified date and Unix epoch. If it fails, then it returns 0. The following example returns the value 1237487400
`hive> SELECT unix_timestamp (‘2009-03-20’, ‘yyyy-MM-dd’);`
OK
1237487400
Time taken: 0.156 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

5)unix_timestamp() :This function returns the number of seconds from the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) using the default time zone.

`hive> select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(‘2000-01-01 00:00:00’);`
OK
946665000
Time taken: 0.147 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

6)unix_timestamp( string date ) :
This function converts the date in format ‘yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss’ into Unix timestamp. This will return the number of seconds between the specified date and the Unix epoch. If it fails, then it returns 0.
`hive> select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(‘2000-01-01 10:20:30’,‘yyyy-MM-dd’);`
OK
946665000
Time taken: 0.148 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

7)unix_timestamp( string date, string pattern ) :
This function converts the date to the specified date format and returns the number of seconds between the specified date and Unix epoch. If it fails, then it returns 0.
`hive> select FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() );`

8)from_unixtime( bigint number_of_seconds [, string format] ) :The FROM_UNIX function converts the specified number of seconds from Unix epoch and returns the date in the format ‘yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss’.

`hive> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP());`

9)To_Date( string timestamp ) :

`hive> select TO_DATE(‘2000-01-01 10:20:30’);`
OK
2000–01–01

10)WEEKOFYEAR( string date )
The WEEKOFYEAR function returns the week number of the date.
`hive> SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(‘2000-03-01 10:20:30’);`
OK
9

11)DATEDIFF( string date1, string date2 )
The DATEDIFF function returns the number of days between the two given dates.
`hive> SELECT DATEDIFF(‘2000-03-01’, ‘2000-01-10’);`
OK
51
Time taken: 0.156 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

12)DATE_ADD( string date, int days )
The DATE_ADD function adds the number of days to the specified date
`hive> SELECT DATE_ADD(‘2000-03-01’, 5);`
OK
2000–03–06

13)DATE_SUB( string date, int days )
The DATE_SUB function subtracts the number of days to the specified date
`hive> SELECT DATE_SUB(‘2000-03-01’, 5);`
OK
2000–02–25
14)DATE CONVERSIONS :Convert MMddyyyy Format to Unixtime

Note: M Should be Capital Every time in MMddyyyy Format

`select cast(substring(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt, ‘MMddyyyy’)),1,10) as date) from sample;`